# Find a permutation that minimizes the Frobenius inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, permutations, algorithms

Given dense, square, positive-valued matrices $A$ and $B$, find a permutation matrix $P$ that minimizes

$\langle PAP^T,B\rangle_F$

where $\langle,\rangle_F$ is the [Frobenius inner product](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Frobenius_inner_product).  Does any polynomial time algorithm exist to find $P$?

Comment: Should that be $PAP^T$ instead? If so, a solution to this problem would lead to a solution to the [graph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem), which means that this problem is $NP$-complete.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes the second one should be transposed.  Updated.  Thanks for catching this!  If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of this problem would lead to a solution of the [graph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem). It follows that this problem is $NP$-complete.